# David Gilmour live at pompeii performance string gauge

Tags: rock, guitar

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26nZZSLs65o) performance David Gilmour seems using a very thick gauge set of strings but I could not be sure which gauge is this. Which gauge does he use?

Comment: I can't say for that particular performance, but I did find a magazine article on his gauges - https://www.stringjoy.com/david-gilmours-guitar-string-gauges/

Comment: It is possibly same. Thank you. If you can post it as an answer I can choose it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David Gilmour's string gauges can be purchased as ready-made 'signature' sets from [GHS](https://www.ghsstrings.com/products/11344-david-gilmour-signature?category_id=1964662-boomers).

It can only be assumed that, as he endorses them, he also uses them ;)

[image]

David Gilmour’s Custom Guitar String Gauges

```
Strat:    .010  - .012 – .016 – .028 – .038 – .048  
Les Paul: .0105 – .013 – .017 – .030 – .040 – .050
```